# why there is error name 'student2dict' is not defined in below code

Tags: python

I just begin to learn python now. Below is some code I tried to test.
My question is:
Now, these code has an error:
name `student2dict` is not defined, when running to `std_data` line.
Can somebody help me figure it out and how to fix it? thanks a lot.

```
import json

class Student(object):

    def __init__(self,name,age,score):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

    def student2dict(std):
        return{
            'name':std.name,
            'age':std.age,
            'score':std.score
            }

s= Student('Penny',20,88)
std_data = json.dumps(s,default=student2dict)
print('Dump Student:',std_data)
```

Comment: There is no global name `student2dict`, because you indented it as a method of the class `Student`. Presumably this is a simple typo that you know how to fix easily. If you don't understand, then please let us know and we can find or write an explanation.

Comment: Also, the `dump` tag is for things like core dumps, not for Python's `dump`/`dumps` functions. I removed it, but for future reference, check the descriptions of tags before using them.

Comment: @abarnert before I tried to use default=s.student2dict instead of dedault=student2dict. But still, lead to some other errors. May you please just write the correct way to use this method student2dict in json.dumps(), thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your existing code is that you don't have a global function (or anything else) named `student2dict`, because you indented it under the `class Student` definition.

Just dedent it, and it will work:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self,name,age,score):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

def student2dict(std):
    return{
        'name':std.name,
        'age':std.age,
        'score':std.score
        }

s= Student('Penny',20,88)
std_data = json.dumps(s,default=student2dict)
print('Dump Student:',std_data)
```

---

However, it seems like you wanted it to be a method, not a plain function:

> before I tried to use default=s.student2dict instead of dedault=student2dict

A normal method needs a `self` parameter. That's how it knows which instance you're calling it on. The error you got was presumably about calling `student2dict` with two arguments (the `s` from `s.student2dict`, and the same `s` again passed in by `json.dumps`) when it only wanted one (`std`).

You could fix this:

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self,name,age,score):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

    def student2dict(self, std):
        return{
            'name':std.name,
            'age':std.age,
            'score':std.score
            }
```

And now you could pass `default=s.student2dict` and it would work.

But this really isn't a very good design. If you're not actually using `self` for anything, you're not really writing an instance method.

---

(You *could* make it a [static method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod), because they neither get nor need a `self`, but I don't see any point to doing that here. If that's what you want, a global function probably makes more sense.)

---

But… what if you got rid of `std`, and used `self` instead?

```
class Student(object):

    def __init__(self,name,age,score):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

    def student2dict(self):
        return{
            'name':self.name,
            'age':self.age,
            'score':self.score
            }
```

Now, you don't want to pass `s.student2dict`, because that's a *bound method*, owned by the instance `s`. It can't be called with an argument, because the argument is already bound in. You're going to get the same error about two arguments instead of one.

What you want is an *unbound method*, which you get by referencing it on the *class*, rather than the instance, so that it can be called later with any instance. like this:

```
s= Student('Penny',20,88)
std_data = json.dumps(s,default=Student.student2dict)
print('Dump Student:',std_data)
```

This works, because `Student.student2dict(s)` does the same thing as `s.student2dict()`. So, if you pass that `Student.student2dict` to the `json.dumps`, when it calls that on `s`, you get exactly what you wanted.